# stroke-dasharray dosent work in CSS with react

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, jsx, react-dom

Hello I have some CSS code.

```css
  stroke-dasharray: 301.637451171875;
  stroke-dashoffset: 301.637451171875;
```

for some reason react DOM doesn't like it and throws a bunch of errors at me.
[image]

I had figured out that some people use `strokeDasharray` in their jsx to by pass this but the problem is that I have a CSS animation so I want to have `stroke-dasharray` in my CSS does anyone know what should I do in This case?

Some more code just in case.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm no expert with React, but maybe importing and applying the CSS in the jsx file? Check out [this](https://www.sanity.io/guides/import-svg-files-in-react) example

Comment: It is not on the screenshot but I do have `import './index.css'` in parent component if you are talking about that and all other CSS code works.

Comment: what I mean is also referencing your CSS with `className={myStyle.upsideArrowPath}` instead of the CSS looking for the SVG by id

Comment: Just to make sure you just want me to change `id='upSideArrowPath'` to `className={myStyle.upsideArrowPath}`?

Comment: Yup, that's what I mean. Sorry if I wasn't all that clear

Comment: This just gives me an error `Cannot find name 'myStyle'` that's just why I wondered.